# confused about typescript modules

Tags: typescript, module, commonjs

i have module file:

```typesript
// class.ts
export default class MyClass {}
module.exports = MyClass // for importing in node.js withous require('./module').default
```

when i import this in node.js, it works:

```
// class-user.js
const Class = require('./class')
const a = new Class() // alright
```

but when i try to use this in typescript:

```
// class-user.ts
import Class from './class'
// class === undefined

// but

import * as Class from './class'
const a = new Class()
// a is instance of Class, but
// [ts] Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
module.exports = MyClass
```

It overwrites your default export.

Use this code for `class.ts`:

```
// class.ts
class MyClass {}
export = MyClass
```

Then, to use it:

```
// class-user.ts
import * as Class from './class'
const a = new Class()
```

Notice: You can't use `default` and `export =` on the same module.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `import * as Class from './class'` you're asking import to pull all exported bindings from the module into your current code file and map it to `Class`.  So in your example the real class you're attempting to reference should be `Class.Class` instead because you have * mapped to `Class`.  So the following should work in your example:

```
const a = new Class.Class()
```

See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import for more detail

Since you're attempting simply to use Class, the following code would be more appropriate ( as you've already noted is working ):

```
import Class from './class'
```